# How can I add values to a Telerik RadGridView column filter that are not (yet) represented in the datasource?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik, radgridview

In a vb.net WinForms application, we have a RadGridView with filtering. We have a column of categories and some users will want to filter to see only rows with specific category. However, the only values represented in the filter popup are what are currently represented in the grid/datasource. Our users want to be able to select a category, even if it is not yet in the grid.

I have seen some mention of OnDistinctValueLoading as a solution online, but it seems I do not have that event on my RadGridView.

I think we're using a custom package for Telerik a coworker put in our nuget feed, but it says Telerik.WinForms 1.0.0. I'm in Vb.Net, .Net framework 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.

I could load the categories on form load with something like this:

```
Private Sub frmMyForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   '...
   LoadAllCategoriesForFilter()
   '...
End Sub

Private Sub LoadAllCategoriesForFilter()
   Dim categories As List(Of String) = GetCategoriesList()
   If categories IsNot Nothing And categories.Count > 0 Then

       rgvMyRadGridView.Columns("colCategory").DistinctValues.Clear()
       For Each category As String In categories
           rgvMyRadGridView.Columns("colCategory").DistinctValues.Add(category)
       Next

    End If
End Sub
```